# scrapy hyphen ignored in xpath attribute

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

At [basketball-reference.com](https://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/tscore.cgi?request=1&match=single&year_min=2013&year_max=2019&team_id=&opp_id=&quarter_is_1=Y&quarter_is_2=Y&quarter_is_3=Y&quarter_is_4=Y&quarter_is_5=Y&is_playoffs=N&round_id=&game_num_type=&game_num_min=&game_num_max=&game_month=&game_location=&game_result=&is_overtime=&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&order_by=date_game&order_by_asc=Y&offset=300) there is a table I am wanting to parse with Xpath and Scrapy. When I try to scrape all of the rows that have the attribute 'data-row' I get nothing.  However, I am able to access the children of the data-rows as long as I don't specifically say 'data-row'.  I believe this has to do with the hyphen being in the attribute name.

```
def parse_item(self, response):

        rows = response.xpath("//tr[@data-row]")
        print(rows)
```

Output = [ ]

I have made a workaround to this, however if I could know what is wrong that would be great.

Comment: is your xpath correct on this question? It looks to be missing the closing `]`

Comment: Also the `data-row` tag attribute is being dynamically added with javascript, it isn't actually part of the response.body.

Comment: any update on this problem?

Comment: Sorry about that, yeah my xpath when I typed it up in the correction was wrong.  I'll edit that.  However, in my code the bracket is there.  I made a work around to it, so I was just curious as to why it wasn't working.  I think your javascript assumption might be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eLRuLL was kind enough to give an answer in the comments of my question.  I believe the '-row' portion was dynamically added via javascript.  I ran in to the problem again on another site.  By using google chrome and going to developer tools->Network->JS, I viewed a script that adds to the class attribute.  I am assuming this is what was happening before based on eLRuLL's comment and that the other website was indeed doing it like that.